# how to pass controls value to url?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

I have a nintex form "A", that has a lot of controls.
I used a label control and in edit source i used html below to link to another form "B".

```
<a onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ url:'http://servername/.../newform.aspx' }); return false;" href="#">my link</a>
```

that works fine.
But I want to show one of form "A"s controls value in form "B".so i want to pass control value with this url to that form using querystring.Is it possible?

i mean use for example `?project=contolname` at the end of url.

Answer (score 0):

you can just keep it the way you have it and append ?project=contolname to the end of the URL and it will go through fine.